# Python list vs. loop what happens to references

Tags: python, object, reference

Here is my example, which works as expected

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,1]})

df_list = [df_1, df_2]
df_list = [x.loc[x['A'] == 1] for x in df_list]

print(df_list[0])
print('____')
print(df_list[1])
```

Here is output:

```
   A
0  1
1  1
____
   A
1  1
```

Here is example, which I expect to produce similar output, but it does not:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,1]})

df_list = [df_1, df_2]

for el in df_list:
    el = el.loc[el['A']==1]

print(df_list[0])
print('____')
print(df_list[1])
```

Here is output

```
   A
0  1
1  1
____
   A
0  2
1  1
```

What is wrong with second example. I am guessing something happening with reference to an object, where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first scenario, you're rewriting a df_list via a list comprehension. The second iterates over a list of data frames, but never changes the data frame itself. They key here is that a list comprehension actually returns a new list, and rewrites df_list.

Here is an illustrative example (excuse all of the print statements..):

```
lst = ['a', 'b']
print('Memory address of the list: %s' % hex(id(lst)))
print('--'*10)
print('BEGIN FOR LOOP')
print('--'*10)
for letter in lst:
    letter = 'c'
print(lst)
print('Memory address of the list: %s' % hex(id(lst)))
print('--'*10)
print('Now use a list comprehension, which will return a new list')
lst = ['c' for letter in lst]
print(lst)
print('Memory address of the list: %s' % hex(id(lst)))
print(letter) # letter is still a variable that has been declared
```

Outputs this:

```
Memory address of the list: 0x10b45b2c8
--------------------
BEGIN FOR LOOP
--------------------
['a', 'b']
Memory address of the list: 0x10b45b2c8  # Same list
--------------------
Now use a list comprehension, which will return a new list
['c', 'c']
Memory address of the list: 0x10b455b08  # New list, new memory spot
```

Note that after using a list comprehension, the memory address actually changed. That means you're looking at an entirely new object. After the for loop, you're looking at the same old list. In the for loop, your making a variable `el` and reassigning it each iteration.

This would do what you're expecting, since you're storing the new value to a new list:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,1]})

df_list = [df_1, df_2]

lst = []
for el in df_list:
    lst.append(el.loc[el['A']==1])

print(lst[0])
print('____')
print(lst[1])
```